# What is the difference between open intervals and standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

Is there any difference between the two?

In these notes it says: http://www.math.cornell.edu/~matsumura/math4530/Intro%20to%20Topology%20week%202.pdf

[image]

But isn't the arbitrary union of open intervals...open intervals. And the intersection of open intervals are...open intervals.

So it seems that the standard topology = all open sets generated by open intervals, is equivalent to the set of all open intervals. Can someone please check?

Comment: Arbitrary intersection of open intervals is not open in general!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is the example you are looking for
$$
(1,2) \cup (3,4)
$$
is open but it is not an interval (that is, it is not in the basis).

Comment: Wow thanks that is so obvious. Woof woof!